# How to reference inverse text color

Tags: android

I've a normal `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_heigh="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/text_on_background"/>
```

It references `@color/text_on_background`. I've a few build flavors of my app, each with different color scheme. So I need to change the color of the text sometimes. But sometimes not, and I want to use default inverse text color from theme.

So i tried these:

```
<color name="text_on_background">?android:textColorPrimaryInverse</color>
<color name="text_on_background">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</color>
```

And it always ended with error about inflating the `TextView`. And I couldn't find any `@color/…inverse…` or `@android:color/…inverse…`.

Any clue how to do that?

Comment: try my answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inverse the Color means , you can do (MAX - COLOR_VAL) in all (R,G,B)

> for example

I Assume `F3FAB6` - this is your color code means you can do following way

```
Color.rgb(255-243, 255-250,255-182);
```

You can get `Inverse Color`.

Comment: That's not what I want. I want text iverse color from theme, not RGB inverse.